# can I use express-rate-limit in sailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, express-rate-limit

I want to use an express-rate-limit middleware in the sails JS framework to prevent brute force attacks/ adding attempts for logging in.

Comment: Have you read through the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware) for registering middleware in SailsJs? A bit down the page it tells you how to use express middleware.

Comment: @Palladium02 thank you very much for your help I really missed that piece of documentation now it's working for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.